# Train from Athens to Thessaloniki: do I need an advance ticket?

Tags: trains, greece, athens, thessaloniki

I've traveled by rail in Europe before, but mostly in the Czech Republic, Germany, and Italy. Next month I'll be in Greece, and I have air tickets into Athens and out of Thessaloniki, with accommodation also booked for several days in each city. That means I'm planning on getting from one place to another on a certain day, but I don't have specific time constraints.

Should I book a ticket in advance, or is it okay to wait until day-of and buy at the station? If I book in advance, am I committing now to a specific time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience it is better to book in advance. Tickets are not impossible to find on the day of the trip but people usually book in advance because the trains might be full. If you choose to book in advance, you are committing  to a specific day and time.

You can book your tickets from the TRAINOSE website:

http://www.trainose.gr/en/

Answer (score 3):

You can book from online but it is also possible to go to Stathmos Larisis in Athens (where all national and international rail services are), go to a kiosk, and buy a ticket there.